# Keep Twitter Bootstrap Tooltip open on mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, preventdefault

For a particular case and element I need to show Bootstrap Tooltip by default (once the page is loaded) an always keep it open (even on mouseover and mouseout).

That's the code I use to open tooltip by default on the element:

```
$('#myelement').tooltip('show');
```

Now I'm not sure how to prevent/disable the default action of tooltip on mouseover & mouseout.
Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Solution found. Manual Trigger does the trick - here is the updated code:

```
$('.taskTooltip').tooltip({trigger: 'manual'}).tooltip('show');
```

Comment: A more standard way would be `$('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip({trigger: 'manual'}).tooltip('show');`. Thanks a lot for this answer

Comment: The above would apply to all tooltips, the behaviour might only be needed for a few hence scoping to a class.

Comment: No longer a valid answer/working - 'show' is no longer an option for tooltip()

Comment: @zanderwar it has never been an option, but a method, and it is still there http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-methods

Comment: @Yuri ahh would've helped if I scrolled down a little further in the docs :D

Answer (score 5):

Use unbind() after show :
it will remove all event handler and thus the tooltip won't hide on mouseleave

```js
$(".circle").tooltip("show");
$(".circle").unbind();
```

```css
.circle{
margin-left:100px;
margin-top:80px;
width:10px;
height:10px;
background-color:#0088ff;
border-radius:50%;
border:1px solid #ff8800;

}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hello World !"></div>
```

Comment: The `.tooltip({trigger: 'manual'})` didn't work for me, but the `.unbind()` worked nice! :)

Comment: i'm glad it helped !

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/shuNaka/o1ncd6r7/

js:

```
$('.switch').on('click touch', function (e) {
  $('.tltip-element').not($(this).parents('.tltip-wrapper').find('.tltip-element')).fadeOut('fast');
  $(this).parents('.tltip-wrapper').find('.tltip-element').fadeToggle('fast');
});
```

html:

```
<div>
  <div class="tltip-wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="switch">
      click me 1 </a>
      <div class="tltip-element" style="display: block;">
        <div class="tltip-content">
          <span>
            test_1
          </span>
          <span class="">
            test_2
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.tltip-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  cursor: default;
}

.tltip-wrapper .tltip-element {
  color: #525252;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px rgba(155, 183, 182, 0.4);
  border: solid 1px #83A7AD;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: -10%;
}

.tltip-wrapper .tltip-element .tltip-content {
  line-height: 0;
}
```