# Bootstrap tool-tip and select drop-down overlap issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with layout that have tool-tip on label with select drop-down.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/eirenaios/pen/ZEzXxjY)

If we open drop-down and then hover on label for tool-tip both overlaps.
I have tried giving max z-index to tool-tip but it is not working.

[image]

The reason looks like tool-tip is having position-absolute and may be select drop-down is position fixed!

To inspect [tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627619/keep-twitter-bootstrap-tooltip-open-on-mouseleave) that keeps it open.

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    container: 'body'
  });
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  z-index: 2147483647 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium, ipsum ratione, soluta veritatis iure earum impedit cumque animi aspernatur distinctio ad omnis. Id, doloribus accusamus nam cupiditate repellat officia aspernatur.">
          Label with tooltip
        </label>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nothing happens when I open the dropdown and hover over the tooltip..

Comment: @Eugene Sunic which browser? I have checked with modern Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Edge its showing there.

Comment: I think it's by design, the browser handle the select element and is probably making it on the top of everything

Comment: I checked with Opera and Chrome and when hovering under the open select box nothing happens with the tooltip

Comment: @Temani Afif yes I also thought the same, Is there any possibility we can overcome this?

Comment: I think your best option may be to close the select dropdown when the tooltip pops up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with CSS only:

```
[data-toggle=tooltip]:hover ~ select:focus{
  display:none;
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    container: 'body'
  });
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  z-index: 2147483647 !important;
}

[data-toggle="tooltip"]:hover~select:focus {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium, ipsum ratione, soluta veritatis iure earum impedit cumque animi aspernatur distinctio ad omnis. Id, doloribus accusamus nam cupiditate repellat officia aspernatur.">
          Label with tooltip
        </label>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wonder how it is removing focus using display property. But its working and CSS only. Accepted :)

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comment, I don't think you can change this behavior since it's handled by the browser. One idea would be to remove the focus from the select on hover and make the dropdown disappear:

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    container: 'body'
  }).hover(function(){
    $('select').blur();
  })
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  z-index: 2147483647 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium, ipsum ratione, soluta veritatis iure earum impedit cumque animi aspernatur distinctio ad omnis. Id, doloribus accusamus nam cupiditate repellat officia aspernatur.">
          Label with tooltip
        </label>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the select element if you hover the tooltip
[Try it online](https://jsfiddle.net/wxy02tkj/)

It's a workaround but if the tooltip covers the select this can be used

```
$( "label" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( "select" ).hide();
  }, function() {
    $( "select" ).show();
  }
);
```

Comment: it hides entire select

Comment: @eirenaios yeah.. didn't I say that in my description?
`It's a workaround but if the tooltip covers the select this can be used`

Comment: oh okay I missed that